# Google Analytics User ID view empty

Tags: google-analytics

I have 2 websites running on 2 separate servers.
The "public" one is www.projacked.com
The "members only" one is global.projacked.com

I enabled cross domain tracking using the linker plugin.

In the internal page I have the following (it's twig on Symfony):

```
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto', {allowLinker: true});
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    {% if app.user is not null %}
        ga('set', 'userId', '{{ app.user.id ~ '-' ~ app.user.username }}'); 
    {% endif %}

    // Loads the Linker plugin
    ga('require', 'linker');

    // Instructs the Linker plugin to automatically add linker parameters
    // to all links and forms pointing to the domain "projacked.com".
    ga('linker:autoLink', ['projacked.com'], false, true);
```

As an example of how the line that sets the user id gets rendered by the template we have:

```
ga('set', 'userId', '1201056-justintrudeau');
```

This line does not report any error in javascript, and I tested that it gets called.
I created a separate view for this. I tried as website to track either www.projacked.com or global.projacked.com. I've enabled user id for this view. In any case I cannot see any user on this view.

This is the configuration for the view:
[image]

I've checked that the snipped is with the same UA-XXXXXXXX-X (of course my code).
 Questions:

- shall I use the members-only website in the view, as it's the only one that can set the userID?
- do I have to make any change in property? There I have only one website (www.projacked.com). Do I have to do anything to make it register stuff also related to the other website (global.projacked.com), apart from adding the same UA-XXXXXXXX-X there too?
- why on hell I don't see the users on the members-only site?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code it looks like you are setting the userId after your pageview call, so it is never actually sent to the server. Move it upwards and things should start to work ("set" calls are not hoisted, they are applied only to hits that follow the "set").

Also the user id and name  might be personally identifiable information and would need to be hashed with at least SHA256 before your are allowed to store it within Google Analytics.

Comment: It works :) . Thank you also for the heads up on hashing. While we are here: shall I use the members only website in view, the "main" external, or it's irrelevant?

Comment: If you mean the url setting, that's irrelevant for data collection (it's used as base url for the preview feature, and used to be used in the now deprecated in-page analysis).

Comment: Thank you again :)